# Break down column to row values

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, pivot

I have a data frame where I have a column named B which has apples and oranges as the data.
How can I basically transform these values as separate columns in the same data frame.

Below is my code-

```
s={'A':[1,1,2,2],'B':['Apples','Oranges','Apples',"Oranges"],'C':[2014,2014,2016,2016],'value':[2,3,4,5]}
p=pd.DataFrame(data=s)
```

The O/p should be column with  A, Apples, Oranges, C

[image]

How can I get this requirement done?

Comment: `new_df = p.pivot(index=['A', 'C'], columns='B', values='value').reset_index()`

Comment: @HenryEcker I don't need am index, then what should I do?

Comment: Every pandas DataFrame has an index whether that’s the default range index or something else.  There is no way to remove it from the DataFrame object. What do you mean "don't need an index" in this context?

Comment: @HenryEcker I don't want A or C as the index, just the nominal ones i.e. 0,1,2,3...

Comment: Oh okay, the `reset_index()` at the end of the code in my first comment does that already no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

s={'A':[1,1,2,2],'B':['Apples','Oranges','Apples',"Oranges"],'C':[2014,2014,2016,2016],'value':[2,3,4,5]}
p=pd.DataFrame(data=s)

frames = []
for u, v in p.groupby("B"):
    frames.append(v.rename(columns={"value": u}).drop(columns=["B"]))

pd.merge(frames[0], frames[1], how="inner", left_on=["A", "C"], right_on=["A", "C"])
```

results in

[image]

This assumes, that `A` is some kind of "index" and that the values in `C` are the same across the rows.